# SOLR 8.7 filtrar por mas de una condición en [child] childDocumentTransformer

Tags: java, sql, apache, condiciones

En solr 8.7 tengo las siguientes configuraciones:

**schema.xml**

```
<schema name="default-config" version="1.6">
    <types>
        <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
        <fieldType name="_nest_path_" class="solr.NestPathField"/>
    </types>

    <fields>
        <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
        <field name="_nest_path_" type="_nest_path_" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
        <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

        <dynamicField name="*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    </fields>

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

**Documentos a indexar:**

```
{
  id: 1,
  object: "doc",
  items: [
    {
      id: 2,
      content: "lorem ipsum same"
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: 3,
  object: "doc",
  items: [
    {
      id: 4,
      content: "hello word same"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      content: "lorem ipsum same"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Query:**

```
q={!parent which="object:doc AND id:*"} +(content:same AND id:4)
fl=*, [child childFilter="smc_content:same AND smc_id:4"]
```

**Resultado actual:**

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "q":"{!parent which=\"object:doc AND id:*\"} +(content:same AND id:4)",
      "fl":"*, [child childFilter=\"content:same AND id:4\"]",
      "_":"1612202589981"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"3",
        "object":"doc",
        "items":[
          {
            "id":"4",
            "content":"hello word same"},
          
          {
            "id":"5",
            "content":"lorem ipsum same"}]}]
  }}
```

El resultado esperado es el siguiente:

```
{
  "id": "3",
  "object": "doc",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "content": "hello word same"
    }
  ]
}
```

He probado diferentes configuraciones que he encontrado en la documentación de SOLR 8.7 y en diversos foros que sugieren que para usar multiples condiciones en el transformador [child] childDocumentTransformer se necesitan definir como variable y entre paréntesis, pero no he podido hacerlo andar. Adjunto el ejemplo de lo detallado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontré la respuesta a mi pregunta después de muchas pruebas. La clave está en la forma que se escribe la condición en el campo **fl**, esta condición genera lo esperado:

```
*, [child childFilter="/items/+(content:\"same\" AND id:4)"]
```

A continuación todos los parámetros configurados:

```
q={!parent which="object:doc AND id:*"} +(content:same AND id:4)
fl=*, [child childFilter="/items/+(content:\"same\" AND id:4)"]
```